# NodeJS packages to handle parallel headless tests on linux box(es) with selenium grid like features?

Tags: node.js, selenium-rc, npm, xvfb

I need to handle authenticated multiple users running parallel tests on the selenium standalone server, and discovered two webdriver clients on nodejs. There's [webdriver-js](https://github.com/dmachi/webdriver-js) and [wd-js](https://github.com/peterbraden/wd). Which is more active and reliable? Any experiences? I'm a bit concerned about them breaking down when node or selenium updates or removes features.

I don't think any of those packages mention automatically starting Xvfb on a unique display number per test. So start shell commands to run xvfb before driving the browser?

The following process is what I am trying to build in nodejs (it's essentially like Grid 2 but on nodejs purpose of continuous integration of tests running) and looking for any packages or suggestions for any of the following part.

1. First authenticate the user(s) using a persistent bi-directional connection (WebSockets or HTTP 1.1)
2. Start/queue tests requested to run by the user on available hardware nodes (I will add more linux boxes so need a package to distribute parallel tests across the "grid")
3. Monitor the running selenium browser tests and send client status updates (ex) running/stop)
4. Tests submitted by the users need to be persistent and accessible for future or continuous integration (couchdb or mysql)
5. Scheduling of jobs to be run on a continuous basis (ex. run every set interval of time).

Is nodejs a bit overkill? should I focus on Java only for the backside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda

This is for vanilla Sauce Labs/Selenium RC integration. I'd imagine when you're running in a browser instance like Selenium RC, websockets should just work, as the javascript on the page is executed. If you're authenticating a user, you want to just fill out whatever form and submit (which triggers your WS auth) as normal.

I don't think nodejs is overkill for this. Node is lightweight. I don't know that I'd add node to my stack ONLY for this, but its certainly convenient and if you have a commitment to javascript, its no big deal.